# How to fix timeout issues with WCF services in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Basically, I (the client) am trying to implement a WCF webservice (configured with HTTPS) in a ASP.NET Web Forms app and I have it configured basically, but it doesn't work. It only works in SoapUI and only when I add WSS TimeToLive more than 1000. In the app, I get the following message:

`An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://webservice.address. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.`

As per the specifications given to me by the author of the web service, I've set the security mode to transport and set it to use username and password. I've set in SoapUI the same settings except specifying to use Transport since there is no such setting in it as far as I know. I also added (as seen above) WSS TimeToLive. All I could find on Google regarding its equivalent in .NET was setting Timeout. I've set Timeout to as much as 10 minutes and it doesn't work. I've tried all timeouts (Close, Open, Receive and Send) more out of desperation than anything else. I still get this message. I've also tried make the binding as wsHttpBinding and give it `<reliableSession inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"/>` as suggested by another forum post. That still did not work. Do you have any suggestions?

This is my current binding:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding()
      {
        Security = new BasicHttpsSecurity()
        {
          Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport,
          Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity
          {
            ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None
          },
          Message = new BasicHttpMessageSecurity
          {
            ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName,
          },
        },
        CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
        OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
        ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0),
        SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0)
      };
      var client = new SISF_to_SIAPortTypeClient(binding,
        new EndpointAddress("webservice.address"));
      client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebServiceUsername"];
      client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebServicePassword"];
      return client;
```

Comment: Are you only testing this in SoapUI?  Have you tried making a "hello world" client app in .net with WCF, just to check it?  The tools in Visual Studio do a thorough job of generating workable client code and configs (as long as mex is enabled on the server).

Comment: I found the relevant post on the forum and I think it will help you[An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https -> Handshake failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764853/an-error-occurred-while-making-the-http-request-to-https-handshake-failed)