# Is it possible to enable TLS via configuration for outgoing web requests in an ASP.NET web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, ssl

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389899/how-do-i-disable-ssl-fallback-and-use-only-tls-for-outbound-connections-in-net) shows how to enable it via code. I'm looking to see if it's possible to do the same thing via the web.config or some other IIS setting. We're looking to not have to redeploy a large application just to enable TLS because we disabled SSL3 on our other web servers.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing out of the box that allows you to do this. If you want to do this in configuration, you could look at creating a custom configuration section to take care of it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

If you're looking to hook this into the WCF runtime, try implementing a `BehaviorExtensionElement`.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/28/wcf-extensibility-behavior-configuration-extensions.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I've done custom config before, but it would require a redeploy of the app - so might as well put in the code in that case. Also, no, this isn't for WCF, just straight up web requests between two servers.