# Google Analytics Access Token - TLS 1.1+

Tags: google-analytics, access-token, tls1.2

I'm using C# to request an access token from Google:

```
string serviceAccountEmail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["analyticsServiceAccountEmail"].ToString();
      string securityKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["analyticsSecurityKeyLocation"].ToString();
      string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["analyticsSecurityPassword"].ToString();

      var certificate = new X509Certificate2(securityKey, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

      var scopes = new List<string> { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics" };

      ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
         new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
         {
           Scopes = scopes
         }.FromCertificate(certificate));

      Task<bool> task = credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);

      task.Wait();

      if (!task.Result || credential.Token == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(credential.Token.AccessToken))
      {
        throw new Exception("Failed to get token from Google");
      }

      return credential.Token.AccessToken;
```

I had to disable TLS 1.0 for PCI compliance.  Since I have done that, this code is breaking with the following error:

> One or more errors occurred.: An error occurred while sending the
>   request.: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error
>   occurred on a receive.: The client and server cannot communicate,
>   because they do not possess a common algorithm

Any suggestions as to how I can make the call using TLS 1.1+?

Comment: check out this [link](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Google-Analytics). It has good info on this.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be done in Application_start through Global.asax:

Please read this before you make change : [How do I disable SSL fallback and use only TLS for outbound connections in .NET? (Poodle mitigation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389899/how-do-i-disable-ssl-fallback-and-use-only-tls-for-outbound-connections-in-net/26392698#26392698)

The way to do it is :

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

This will turn on communication support for SSL3, falling back to TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 as applicable.

Comment: Isn't SSL 3.0 less secure than TLS 1.1?  In any case I only want TLS 1.1+.  When I do this the call to Google Analytics fails.  It only works if I enable TLS 1.0.