# WCF secure connection should initiate connection with TLS 1.2 protocol

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, ssl

I am trying to achieve to have a server set up which will only provide secure connection with TLS 1.2 protocol.

On the server I disabled the the SSL 2, SSL 3, TLS 1.0. By regedit [using this way](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/kb/187498#kb-link-6).
I have a simple ASP.NET application and an _AppStart.cshtml file where I am logging what is happening.

This is the code and output I have now ([mostly got it from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389899/how-do-i-disable-ssl-fallback-and-use-only-tls-for-outbound-connections-in-net)):

```cs
Log("SecurityProtocol: " +  System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.ToString());
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; 
Log("SecurityProtocol: " +  System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.ToString());
```

output:

```cs
-- Log: SecurityProtocol: Ssl3, Tls
-- Log: SecurityProtocol: Tls12
```

In the beginning somehow the value is still Ssl3, Tls

Is there any way to set up (maybe in web.config/app.config file) to initially start connection with forcing TLS 1.2?

One step would be achieving this by browsing this web application, another would be to have this working between a web- and application server with WCF.
Any good pointers and ideas how to do this? I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

See "Using TLS 1.2 with WCF" article by Benjamin Perkins: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/11/04/using-tls-1-2-with-wcf/.
At the least .NET Framework 4.5 should be used and the following hotfix should be applied:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2960358

Comment: Thanks! This looks like something I would be interested in. I will try.