# Disable <TLS 1.2 in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, tls1.2

I have a web app for which I'm trying to disable versions of TLS that are older than 1.2.  ie: I do not want to support TLS 1.0 or 1.1.

1) I've set the below in Azure Portal.

[image: SSL Disabled in Azure Portal]

2) I created a simple webpage and uploaded it.

3) In IE Internet Options I disabled all TLS

[image: Internet Options - Disabled TLS]

4) I try to load the simple webpage and I correctly get the right error message.

[image: Enable TLS error page from webpage]

5) I enable TLS 1.0 only, refresh the webpage and it still works (I've tried this from multiple systems to avoid caching issues).  This shouldn't work as TLS 1.2 is still disabled.

I've tried googling the error and only found [How to know if an Azure Server is under TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279777/how-to-know-if-an-azure-server-is-under-tls-1-2) which doesn't work.  Has anyone got this working?

Answer (score 2):

> I enable TLS 1.0 only, refresh the webpage and it still works (I've tried this from multiple systems to avoid caching issues). This shouldn't work as TLS 1.2 is still disabled.

We could get App Service Team's reply from this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2018/04/17/app-service-and-functions-hosted-apps-can-now-update-tls-versions/). It will work soon.

> This will only **launch toward the middle of May**, due to the discovery of a breaking change this has the potential of causing.