# A intermittently occuring CommunicationException when calling a WCF service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, wcf, ssl-certificate, wshttpbinding

Having some troubles with troubleshooting a intermittently occuring error. It can go weeks between occurences and lasts an seemingly random amount of time.

We're making a call to a WCF service which service we have imported into our ASP.net MVC project. The call is made based on user input, at a forms submission.

As of a while ago it never had any issues and had run for about a year prior to the issues starting to occur.

From our end, we get the error:
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while making the HTTP request to . This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.

From their end they say on the requests that fail they can't see we're including the authorization header.

From googling it seems the likely cause would be they removed support older TLS protocols from their service. But they claim they haven't done any changes and the fact that the issue only occurs rarely seems to speak against that. Unless they have a load balanced enviroment (but from what I understand they do not) where perhaps one instance that is rarely hit would be causing the error. Last time the error occured it lasted for about a day though.

I think we'll try updating the tls protocols used and .NET framework (Currently 4.6.1) on our end regardless though.

Another thought we had was that perhaps it would be an issue in azure where our site is hosted. Like if one of the appservice instances for one reason or another was having the issue, but even then it seems like it would be occuring more often and somewhat consistently.

Anyone had similar issues or has some experience troubleshooting similar WCF-service error which could give some pointers where suitable troubleshooting tasks?

Any help greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solutions found on the Internet are basically changes to the TLS version, and the required TLS protocol is not enabled. Try to check the TLS version under
this path (HKLM SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\ channel) to see if it matches.

Or check out [this Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389899/disable-ssl-fallback-and-use-only-tls-for-outbound-connections-in-net-poodle) for some other solutions.

Comment: Thanks, we've updated to framework 4.8 and see if that makes any difference. 

I still can't quite understand how it could occur intermittently if it was a TLS issue, but I sure am hoping it is :)